# «Вроде»: запятая или ничто отнюдь?

Tags: запятые

Как правильно?

1.1. Правильно писать *предыюльский*, вроде.

1.2. Правильно писать *предыюльский* вроде.

А если так-таки?

2.1. Правильно писать вроде *предыюльский*.

2.2. Правильно писать, вроде, *предыюльский*.

Comment: Что за "ничто отнюдь"?

Comment: То есть «вообще ничего».

Comment: Вы это сами придумали или где-то слышали? Можно услышать "отнюдь ничего".

Comment: Это Лео, т. е. я.

Comment: Удивляюсь, как это у вас может нормально звучать. Или просто кошачий набор слов?

Comment: Вы мало отвечаете, но много пустословите. Sharon, однако, наоборот всё делает-таки.

Comment: Это не пустословие. Это сайт о грамотности, а не стол заказов. Всё делает, но часто неправильно.

Comment: У Sharon примерно каждый третий ответ неверный. Не надо её возносить. С ней многие ругались из-за этого. А другие таки правильно отвечают.

Comment: Любопытно-с.  А я это еще не читала...  Даже статистика приведена)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

(1) *Правильно писать предыюльский, // **вроде**.*

Наречие в значении вводного слова. Выражает **сомнение**, позиция в конце слова позволяет обозначить **паузу.**

(2) *Правильно писать / **вроде** предыюльский.*

Структура в большей степени   соответствует простому предложению.

**Примечание** (можно добавить частицу БЫ): *Правильно писать / **вроде бы** предыюльский.* Частица БЫ подчеркивает сомнение.

Comment: Но если *бы* убрать? Говорят же, что в конце факультативно обособление *вроде*.

Comment: В первом предложении нет частицы БЫ, при выборе знака сказывается влияние позиции в конце слова. А во втором да, нет обособления и без частицы БЫ.  Там она факультативна.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны:

«Правильно писать *предыюльский* вроде»;

«Правильно писать вроде _предыюльский_».

Частица *вроде* имеет значение *кажется* , и еë можно заменить на синонимы *вроде как*, *вроде бы*. Она не требует обособления запятыми.

Грамота.ру:

[image: грамотару]

Comment: Но говорят же то, что, когда она в конце, её факультативно можно обособлять-таки.